# List comprehension to return the sum of n/2...?

Tags: python, range

Basically, how do I write the same function in list comprehension?

```
def blah(n):
    if n <= 1:
        return 1
    return n + blah(n/2)

print blah(32)
```

I don't really need this for anything other than proving to myself that custom step for any range in list comprehension is actually possible.

Comment: There is no list here. Can you give us a for loop example at all?

Comment: What is wrong with `[blah(i) for i in range(32)]` for example?

Comment: And `blah()` is a recursive function, did you want it unrolled perhaps?

Comment: >What is wrong with [blah(i) for i in range(32)]

It's not a list [32,16,8,...]

Comment: That was not clear, your question was ambiguous.

Comment: Is someone going to solve this easy recurrence and provide the closed-form solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'd need to generate the sequence of halved numbers:

```
def halved(n):
    while n:
        yield n
        n >>= 1
```

Then use turn that into a list:

```
list(halved(32))
```

or just directly sum it:

```
sum(halved(32))
```

You'd have to use `math.log()` to turn that into a `range()`-suitable value:

```
import math
sum(n >> i for i in range(int(math.log(n, 2)) + 1))
```

Comment: I got infinite loop using that

Comment: That's because I got the shift direction mixed up. Try again.

Comment: ok, works. I have nothing more to say, but stackoverflow forces me to write more.

Answer (score 5):

```
import math
def lcsum(n):
    return sum([n>>i for i in range(int(math.log(n, 2))+1)])
```

Comment: why did you add the list comp back in?

Comment: The question specifically asked for a list comprehension, and until the list is extremely large, a list comprehension will sum faster than an equivalent generator expression. Since the size of the list grows as O(log(n)), it would take an extremely large `n` before the generator expression version would be faster than the list comprehension version.

Comment: alright doing it just because the question says to is not required but the second part makes sense

Answer (score 1):

I would write it like this, if you  really wanted some kind of list comprehension in there:

```
import math

def sumOfNHalf( n ):
   return sum( [ 2**x for x in range( 0, int( math.log( n, 2 ) + 1 ) ) ] )
```